# Find the ON-base

Tags: linear-algebra, orthonormal

I can't figure out the b) question. I know that I am supposed to use the formula $ x^tAx$ but what does $ x^tAx$ mean? How can I figure out what the martix A is?

[Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GD2jy.jpg)

Comment: Please edit the question into the body of your question, instead of asking users to chase a picture offsite.

Answer (score 0):

Here $x$ is a 2-dimensional vector:
$x = \begin{bmatrix}
    x_1 \\
    x_2 \\
  \end{bmatrix}$.
So
$$x^\mathsf{T}Ax = 
  \begin{bmatrix}
    x_1 & x_2 \\
  \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    a_{11} & a_{12} \\
    a_{21} & a_{22} \\
  \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    x_1 \\
    x_2 \\
  \end{bmatrix}
=a_{11}x_1^2 + (a_{12} + a_{21})x_1x_2 + a_{22}x_2.
$$
That's definition of a quadratic form. In practice, we write $A$ as a symmetric matrix, so that calculations are easier.
$$
ax_1^2 + bx_1x_2 + c x_2^2 \quad \rightsquigarrow \quad
A = \begin{bmatrix}
    a & \frac b 2 \\
    \frac b 2 & c \\
  \end{bmatrix}
$$
In that form, we can diagonalize $A$ with orthonormal change-of-basis matrix. That is for any symmetric matrix $A = A^\mathsf{T}$ there exist diagonal $J$ and invertable $P$ such that $A = P J P^\mathsf{T}$, and $P^{-1} = P^\mathsf{T}$. We want to find that $P$, because it will give us the diagonal form: $$
x^\mathsf{T}A x = x^\mathsf{T} P J P^\mathsf{T} x
= (P^\mathsf{T}x)^\mathsf{T} J (P^\mathsf{T}x)
= (P^{-1}x)^\mathsf{T} J (P^{-1}x)
= u^\mathsf{T} J u.
$$
Here $u$ is vector written in the new basis.

In our case we have $2x_1^2 + 2x_1x_2 + 2x_2$, so $a = 2, \frac b 2 = 1, c = 2$.
We diagonalize $\begin{bmatrix}
    2 & 1 \\
    1 & 2 \\
  \end{bmatrix}
$, and pick eigenvectors with norm 1. You should get someting similar to $$
\begin{bmatrix}
    2 & 1 \\
    1 & 2 \\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
   -\frac 1 {\sqrt 2} & \frac 1 {\sqrt 2} \\
    \frac 1 {\sqrt 2} & \frac 1 {\sqrt 2} \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 \\
    0 & 3 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
   -\frac 1 {\sqrt 2} & \frac 1 {\sqrt 2} \\
    \frac 1 {\sqrt 2} & \frac 1 {\sqrt 2} \\
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Now take $u = P^T x$ and get $u_1 = \frac{-x_1 + x_2}{\sqrt 2}, u_2 = \frac{x_1 + x_2}{\sqrt 2}$. Our quadratic form is now $u_1^2 + 3 u_2^2$. You can plug in definition of $u$ to see that it is correct.